# How to call function that is bijective only for some ranges and undefined/unreachable otherwise

Tags: functions

How does one call a function such that

- each element of the domain is mapped to *maximally* one element of the co-domain (well, I guess that is the case for every function) but might be undefined for some elements of the domain, and
- every element of the co-domain is reached from *maximally* one element of the domain, but some elements of the co-domain might not be reached.

The function might be bijective, but does not have to be, for example

$$
f(x) = \exp{(x)} · \sqrt{x}
$$

(the domain and co-domain are the real numbers) would also be a valid function of the type I am looking for.

Comment: Your first bullet point... for a function to be called a function, *by definition* there must be *exactly* one output for each input.  You talk about "*maximally*"... there is no way to have more than one.  That would not be a function.  Perhaps we might call that a "*multi-valued function*" but that is not a function.  You talk about "*but might be undefined for some elements of the domain.*"  That is not a function.  You can not have the result be undefined for any given inputs.  The domain-codomain of a function are strictly part of the definition of the specific function in question.

Comment: So... ignoring the first bullet point then... you ask about a function who has for each element in the codomain at most one element of the domain who maps to it... that is what we call "*injectivity.*"  The types of functions you ask for are the *injective* functions.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Well, maximally, here, basically means 0 or 1 output value. As you put it, $f(x) = sqrt(x)$, where the domain and co-domain are the real numbers, is not a function. That would be news to me...

Comment: @JMoravitz:  I suspect your answer is that the real numbers are not the domain, but only the real numbers that are larger or equal to 0. But then I find it weird, that we do not call the image of the function the co-domain, instead of that which we do call the co-domain. This would seem pretty inconsistent.

Comment: I would say that each of these are different functions:  $f~:~\Bbb N\to\Bbb N,~n\mapsto |n|$, and $g~:~\Bbb N\to\Bbb Z,~n\mapsto |n|$, and $h~:~\Bbb Z\to\Bbb N,~n\mapsto |n|$, and $\ell~:~\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z,~n\mapsto |n|$, each with different properties.  The domain and codomain are inextricably part of what makes it what it is.  Here, $f,g$ are injective, and $f,h$ are surjective.  $\ell$ is neither, $f$ is both.  Yes, we might loosely talk about $y(x)= |x|$ as a function without mention of domain or codomain, but that is improper and ambiguous.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I see your point, thank you, and I agree with you readily. Now, I would have thought that if we replace each of your $n \mapsto | n | $ with $n \mapsto \sqrt{n} $, then all of those functions would still be (different) functions.

Comment: *Partial* functions perhaps, but not functions since they are not everywhere-defined.  $\sqrt{2}$ is not a natural number nor an integer and so either is said not to exist or at least exists outside of the codomain for your example.  Read [wikipedia's entry on functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Total,_univalent_relation) and note the distinction between the terms "function" and "partial function"

Comment: @JMoravitz: Possibly, my mental framework of a function has always been that of a functional relation, which (in common terminology) is not a function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Special_types_of_binary_relations (but in fact a partial function). I am (relatively) sure, that my professors would have written $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow R, x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ without qualms. However, I originate from engineering, so maybe they were not so rigorous about this.

Answer (score 1):

The second bullet is the injectivity, as noted by @JMoravitz.

For the functions-or-not-functions as per the first bullet, I started to call them *partial functions* recently. It has some support on the [web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).

(Not to be confused with potential term *partial-function-2* that would be natural for multivariate functions because of the term *partial derivatives*. That would be  called *partial application* by computer scientists, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), but mathematicians would not feel that as natural.)

So we end up with *injective partial function*.

Comment: “Partial function” has been a standard term in recursive function theory for at least 75 years.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss Thank you! -- that helps me not to feel guilty.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be describing a *partial bijection*, or equivalently an injective [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have a function that maps
$$
f:A\rightarrow B
$$
if no two input items in $A$ overlap when $f$ is applied, then we say $f$ is *injective*.

We can define the set of all items that $f$ maps to as the *image of $A$ under $f$*
$$
im(f)=\{f(a)|a\in A\}.
$$

If the image of $A$ is equal to the codomain $B$, then we say that $f$ is surjective; every item in $B$ is mapped to by something in $A$.

Your second point is asking about the case when $f$ is injective, but not surjective, which other users have mentioned is a partial function on $B$. Note though that $f$ is bijective if you set the codomain to $im(f)$